# How do I enhance slugify to handle Camel Case?

Tags: javascript, regex, slug, camelcasing

I'd like to write a JavaScript function to [slugify a string](http://dense13.com/blog/2009/05/03/converting-string-to-slug-javascript/), with one more requirement: handle Camel Case. For example, `thisIsCamelCase` would become `this-is-camel-case`.

How do I modify a [function like this](http://dense13.com/blog/2009/05/03/converting-string-to-slug-javascript/) to do so?

**EDIT**

Added full, [answered example](http://jsfiddle.net/wraithmonster/AAwTT/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add one line of code to what you posted

```
str = str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(s){ return "-" + s; });
```

This brings the remaining code to be

```
function string_to_slug(str) {
  str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // trim
  str = str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(s){ return "-" + s; }); // camel case handling
  str = str.toLowerCase();

  // remove accents, swap ñ for n, etc
  var from = "àáäâèéëêìíïîòóöôùúüûñç·/_,:;",
      to   = "aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuunc------";
  for (var i=0, l=from.length ; i<l ; i++) {
    str = str.replace(from[i], to[i]);
  }

  str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '') // remove invalid chars
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-') // collapse whitespace and replace by -
    .replace(/-+/g, '-'); // collapse dashes

  return str;
}
```

Edit :: I also deleted the useless new RegExp logic too.
Edit :: Added 'g' to find all caps, not just the first one.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I added the full example here http://jsfiddle.net/wraithmonster/AAwTT/

Answer (score 0):

This will help you!

```
     var strings = 'toDo';
var i=0;
var ch='';

while (i < strings.length){
    character = strings.charAt(i);
        if (character == character.toUpperCase()) {
            //alert ('upper case true' + character);
        character = "-" + character.toLowerCase();
        }
      i++;
      ch += character;
    }
//to-do
      alert(ch);
```

Comment: This isn't pretty to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
str=str.toLowerCase() before or after the slugification.
```

Comment: This does not add the hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to generate a slug in snake keys. This method worked for me

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.slugGen', function () {
   let slug = $(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_').replace(/[^\w-]+/g, '');
   $(this).closest('tr').find('#slug').val(slug);
});
```